# How to show tables in databricks without views?

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

The `SHOW TABLES IN mydb` query lists tables and views, while `SHOW VIEWS IN mydb` only lists views. Is there any way to list only the tables of a given database ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any way to do that completely in SQL, so here is an answer that uses also Python.

1. Get the list of views to dataframe
2. Get the list of tables to dataframe
3. Remove views from table list (by using antijoin)
4. If needed, create a temp view to use this list in SQL

```
table_list_df = spark.sql("show tables in mrr")
view_list_df = spark.sql("show views in mrr").withColumnRenamed("viewName","tableName")
table_list = table_list_df.join(view_list_df,"tableName","anti")
table_list.createOrReplaceTempView("only_tables")
```